# Submit Html form with a specific model

Tags: excel, razor, knockout.js, export, typescript

I am using MVC, Razor, Knockout, typescript in my application. Need to prepare a excel file with a model/dataset that is set at client side. I am using the following code but the problem i understand is that the dataset is being taken as string and not exactly like the model it is supposed to take as. Here is the code

This is observable (dataset)

```
 vmExportData = ko.observableArray<ExcelModel>([]);
```

Push data to the dataset

```
vmExportData.push(new ExcelModel (
e.sender.data()[i].Id,
e.sender.data()[i].Name, 
e.sender.data()[i].Address1,
));
```

Html code, to prepare excel file (at the controller)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ExportToExcel", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div data-bind="css:{hidden: true}">
<input type="text" data-bind="value: vmExportData" />
</div>
<input class='excelIcon' type="submit" data-ux-access="true" value="">
}
```

Controller method :

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(ExportModel exportModel)
        {
```

The problem is, the exportModel parameter value is coming as null ! Any other way out to get it to work ? Is there a way to make excel at client side and render as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `name="exportModel"` on  your  tag.

Also make sure to have an `[HttpPost]` on top of your controller action, since your form method is post.

What does the ExportModel class look like?

Comment: No luck ! The ExportModel looks like ExcelModel (client side)